# Is that "modify()" or "update()" necessary in a drools rule?

Tags: drools

I have two rules, they have same salience,same LHS but different RHS. I want the two rule will be both  executed. However, both of them will make the LHS pattern can not be matched again. If I use modify() or update(), there must be one of them can not be executed. 
Is there some strategy that making the drools know that the working Memory has been changed after all RHS have been executed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One could argue that having two rules with the same LHS is poor design. This is especially so if the RHS of one or the other intends to modify one or more of the participating facts.

So the first advice is: combine the right hand sides so that you have a single rule.

The next best would be to make the firing order deterministic. Use salience in both, so that their relative oder is guaranteed. Move all update/modify calls to the rule with lower salience.

Finally, there's no need to use update/modify **if the changes need not be "seen" by the rule engine.** This (what I call) "dirty update" is handy where information should be accumulated but does not have any influence on LHS logic.

Comment: And...mmm..There is another problem.What if the two rules change the same fact(but different members of this fact, which is a Java bean.) ？Thank you very much！

Comment: It is beyond the capacity of a comment to enlarge on that, but that might be handled with careful writing of constrainst, and also the "property reactive" feature could be the way to go.

Comment: Sorry for bothering you.Could I ask you one more question? Is there any other way to tell rule engine that the working Memory has been changed?(Without modify() or update()).I want to automatically update the working Memory just like CLIPS.Thank you very much!

Comment: Perhaps "property reactive" is what is best in your scenario. This should be discussed with a simple example, i.e., a Java class with two or three fields, a couple of rules indicating what you have in mind. Please provide this in another question.

Comment: i.e the Java class has three properties,a1,a2 and a3. They are all boolean variables.The rule one is if "a1 is true“ then ”a1 is false,a2 is true",the rule two is if "a1 is true" then "a1 is false,a3 is true"

Comment: if I input a1 is true, what should i do if i want to get the result that both a2 and a3 are true?Thank you very much!

Comment: Now we are definitely back to the first paragraph of my answer. To see this, simply use these two rules `when a1 then a1=false; a2=true;` and `when a1 then a1=false; a3=true;` as if statements. Is there any order in which they would produce `a2=a3=true`? No. Since rule firings happen in some order, there's no way here either. Specification and/or design error.